SCP through an ssh tunnel to the "same" remote machine, but reusing proxy authentication
I have a remote machine. The way we access to that machine is through a token (obtained by using "One Identity Safeguard for Privileged Passwords") of the kind vaultaddress=someip@token=blabla@pam-xxx@blabla@remote_ip@someip3, but we don't work with pam-xxx but with useful-user. So once we ssh vaultaddress=blabla, we then ssh useful-user@localhost and then we start working. We ssh inside the remote machine (instead of using su - useful-user) to avoid writting the useful-user's password.
The problem with the token is that we can't reuse it, and for scp that's a huge problem, because for each copy operation we have to obtain a new token, making the process very error prone and also making using any tool that requires specifying some user and ip configuration to automate the use of scp impossible.
I was thinking of opening an ssh tunnel to :22 on the remote machine to "reuse" the authentication, but I haven't been able to make it work.
I first do ssh -L 9999:localhost:22 vaultaddress=blabla, keep the session open, and in another terminal then scp -P 9999 local-file real-user@localhost:/remote-folder, but it does not work because scp is trying to locate the key using my local machine user, which is my_name instead of pam-xxx. If I scp -v -P ... I can see how he is trying to locate /home/my_name/.ssh/id_rsa which doesn't exist.
How can I scp files directly as useful-user, or at least as pam-xxx, using the ssh tunnel? What I want to do is to be able to reuse the token so that I can get a set of fixed ip, port and user parameters that I can use to configure some of my tools.
NOTE: I'm looking for a Windows solution (master connections doesn't work there).

Possibly your problem is in its mechanics almost identical to this one. Maybe you can adapt my answer to your needs. Keep in mind scp uses ssh as transport, so first you should set things up so ssh B "just works" from your local. Then scp should also work or some adjustments will be needed.

@KamilMaciorowski I finally made it work with an ssh tunnel and a python http server listening to a random port on the remote host that receive files, and now I can upload files from local using curl. I don't like the solution but it's the only thing I was able to make it work.

@KamilMaciorowski Regarding your answers and links, my knowledge on ssh is limited and I don't fully understanding what is said there, but master connections are not implemented for windows, and also, if I'm not wrong, about ssh tunnels, they just forward TCP packets from port to port right?

@KamilMaciorowski  I can't do something like ssh -L 9999:localhost:22 connection  and expect that ssh -P 9999 blabla gives me an already authenticated connection or something, REGARDLESS of the options I use, right? If I want to login on the remote host, I have to start from scratch regardless of the authentication status of the tunnel, right?

"master connections are not implemented for windows" – This I don't know, but it's the first time you mentioned Windows. Maybe [edit] and clarify what OS is used where.

Wouldn't this be a normal SSH multi-hop, or am I misunderstanding? Normally a multi-hop is connecting to a different SSH server through an existing SSH tunnel (e.g. needing to SSH into a downstream LAN server from WAN through the SSH connection of the WAN router), however it's the same for connecting to the same SSH server through an existing SSH tunnel on the same SSH server

@JW0914 Not sure if that's a normal SSH multi-hop. If you provide what you think would be the corresponding commands, I will try them to see if it works.
